# running two ionic 3 apps on the same device

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

The issue can be replicated with the tutorial templates. I installed the blank and sidemenu templates using the CLI: ionic start First blank and ionic start Second sidemenu. If you build and put them on a device the following problem occurs.

The problem occurs only on iOS. If you start one of them, when you minimize it (by pushing the phone button), if you immediately start the 2nd app (in the first 5 seconds after you minimized the 1st app - i think it's because of the iOS app lifecycle that sends the app to background after 5s) then the 2nd app starts the first app. But if you wait 5 seconds after minimizing the first app and then start the second app then it works, the second app actually starts.

I tested this on ionic 3.9.2
a) Ionic CLI 3.20.0, Cordova CLI 8.0.0, Node 8.11.1, npm 5.6.0, windows 10
b) Ionic CLI 3.20.0, Cordova CLI 8.1.1, Node 8.11.2, npm 6.4.1, macOS Sierra

Is there a solution for this? Can I have two Ionic 3 apps installed on the same iOS device and when I minimize the first one if I immediately start the second one it will actually start the second one and not the first? What can I do? What options do I have?

Thank you.

Comment: Try changing the id of your app in the config.xml from "io.ionic.start" to something specific for each app.

Comment: I've done that so I could install both templates on the same device. Other ideas? :)

Comment: I have a few ionic 3 apps on the same iOS device.  I can't recreate what you're seeing.  I've done a few quick minimize + second app start attempts.  Each attempt starts the proper app for me.

Comment: I am using the ionic official templates https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/tutorial/ .
I've created two apps using the CLI: 
1) ionic start FirstApp blank 
2) ionic start SecondApp sidemenu.

I've built each app using the terminal: ionic cordova build ios and then using Xcode I run them on my phone. I've tried this on 3 different phones. They all behave the same way.

Can you replicate that? I've done it I think 10 times and the result is the same. What can I do so I don't have to wait 5 seconds between minimizing one app and starting the other?

Thanks!

Comment: The guys from Ionic responded. There was already an opened issue and they are working on it -> https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview/issues/165

Thanks anyway :)